# Smart Table plugins don't work

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

This is my HTML:

```
<table st-table="prizesByCompany" st-safe-src='safePrizesByCompany' class="table table-striped"  >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort='status'>Filtros</th>
            <th st-sort='text'>Campanha</th>
            <th>
                <button class="btn" ui-sref='campaignAdd'>Nova Campanha</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"><input st-search="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquise..." type="text"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="row in prizesByCompany">
            <span ng-if="row.status != 1">
                <td>
                    <button class="btn" >{{row.status | company_status_button}}</button>
                </td>
                <td><a ui-sref = 'campaignView({action: "view", id:{{row.id}}})'>{{row.text}}</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-if='row.status == 2'>
                        <button class='btn' ui-sref='campaignEditRequest({id: {{row.id}}})'>Editar</button>
                        <button class='btn'>Solicitar Pausa </button>
                        <button class='btn' ng-click='deactivateCampaign($index)'>Solicitar Cancelamento</button>
                        <button class='btn'>Relatório</button>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if='row.status == 3'>
                        <button class='btn' ng-click='activateCampaign($index)'>Solicitar Reativação</button>
                        <button class='btn'>Relatório</button>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if='row.status == 1'>
                        <button class='btn' ng-click='activateCampaign($index)'>Solicitar Reativação</button>
                        <button class='btn'>Relatório</button>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </span>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table displays fine, but plugins doesn't work.

About the collections:

```
                $scope.prizesByCompany = data.response
                $scope.safePrizesByCompany = angular.copy($scope.prizesByCompany);
```

It doesn't show any error.
I checked out Smart Table documentation to see if I'm marking up something wrong, but it seems to be everything OK. I got no idea of what to do now.

What can be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is due to the typo of st-safe-src you have in the table markup (instead of str-safe-src). You should as well write attributes values with double quotes

```
<th st-sort="status">Filtros</th>
<th st-sort="text">Campanha</th>
```

Also, you should use same references for your collections:

```
$scope.safePrizesByCompany = data.respsonse
$scope.prizesByCompany = [].concat($scope.safePrizesByCompany) // actually you don't even need this line and can simply remove it
```

Comment: yes but in the sample you provided, you wrote str-safe-src ;)

Comment: LOL you're right. sorry. But this is not the problem, unfortunately. I would be happy if it was just a typo.